# Why Can't I get rid of the white space above my block on the website? Something to do with <body>?

Tags: html, css, web

Before anything else, I'm very new to html/css, and this is probably the easiest fix ever, but I can't seem to find it.  also apologies if I formatted the code wrong, some people are using js fiddle but if someone could also explain how that works, that would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Please look at image for context]

```css
.block1{
    display: block;
    background: url(images/cute\ penguins.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    block-size: 1080px;
   padding: 0px;
    
   
    
}
.company-logo{
    width: 140px;
    
    position: absolute; 
    left: 190px;
    
    

}


body{
  
   margin: 0;
 
}


#title{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; top: 150px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: UniSansHeavy;
}
.Flow{
    color: rgba(94, 8, 255, 0.664);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: UniSansHeavy;
    src: url(Uni\ Sans\ Heavy.otf);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>PenguinFlow- We'll Make Your Business Flow.</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/pgfavicon.ico"
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block1">
        <img class="company-logo" src="images/Option 3.png">
        <h1 id="title"> We'll Make Your Business <span class="Flow">Flow.</span></h1>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So you can see in the image above there is white space above my image. I thought it because  has some default margins to get rid of, so tried setting the body's margin to 0 but that doesn't do anything

weirdly if I set the  padding of  the "block 1"  that contains all the elements of the first block to just 1px, it gets rid of it, which makes no sense
must be some default margins of the body that I cant change or something

So you can see in the image above there is white space above my image. I thought it because  has some default margins to get rid of, so tried setting the body's margin to 0 but that doesn't do anything

weirdly if I set the  padding of  the "block 1"  that contains all the elements of the first block to just 1px, it gets rid of it, which makes no sense
must be some default margins of the body that I cant change or something

Comment: You need standard classes from normalize.css added....example: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the default margin of the `h1` element inside the `block1` container is what's responsible for the white space above your image. To remove the margin from the `h1` element, add the following code to your CSS file:

```
#title {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked! I guess by default the h1 element has some margins. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the div with the class of `block1` and see if that makes a difference. If doing that removes the white space, then at least you know where the problem lies.

I think you add the background image css to the body tag directly in your css. Adding a div tag to do that seems unnecessary.

Comment: the reason I'm doing that is because I only want that background image to be for the first block of my website, then the next block is a different background.  look at my previous site and you'l see what I mean https://penguinflow.ucraft.site/